# GrovePI and Android Things compatibility

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things, grovepi+

I want to develop an app with Android Things on a RapsberryPI 3

https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html

My app will need a GPS and accelerometer. I saw that the Grove sensors are a good solution for this purpose and I think I will buy those:

http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-GPS/

http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-3-Axis_Digital_Accelerometer-16g/

And in between I will have a GrovePI+ to connect the sensors to the RapsberyPI. But I don't understand if it will work seamless with Android Things? According to the documentation I found, I need to install drivers to be able to talk with the sensors:

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/awesome-android-things

But will it be enough? Or do I need something more to communicate with the GrovePI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GPS (seems it has UART interface) example please see [this](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps) driver sample and other UART samples like [this](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback). For Grove - 3 Axis Digital Accelerometer (seems it has I2C interface) please see [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/i2c.html) and projects like [this](http://android.geek.nz/i2c-with-android-things-part-2/) or [that](https://medium.com/proandroiddev/android-things-analog-i-o-and-pwm-spi-i%C2%B2c-tutorial-with-the-raspberry-pi-5bbc957099da).